# Gulp-Sass error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

Have installed gulp-cli, gulp and gulp-sass globally and created the gulpfile.js as below.  When I type "gulp" in the command line and press enter, it always gives me an exception saying that: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Is there anything else I need to do to make the gulp-sass working?

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task("default", function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've already solved it. See [this issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/468). I solved it by reinstalling gulp-sass.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here there is a file named %ur proj path%\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding
this binding file is supposed to be an exe.
but sometimes its blocked by proxies or nw errors. so It downloads a file not found html file instead.
so the solution is to delete this file and remove node-sass and re install it

```
npm rm node-sass
```

wait until it succeeds
then

```
npm i node-sass
```

wait until it succeeds

now gulp will start working